# Compare two set of linestrings

Tags: postgis

I have two sets of linestrings which have to perfectly overlap. The set A have to contains the set B (the A is a combination of multiple Bs which are touching each other).

I would like to build a query to easily spot the vertices where it doesn't match.

For now I developped a query based on `ST_DumpPoint` on each dataset, and I was checking for the point from A that don't match any point from B. It worked well on small datasets, but the one I am currently working on results in 15K points for A and 9K for B, so something like 150M match to compare. It takes forever (and I stop it after 2min of running).

I also tried to use `ST_SymDifference`, but it just give me everything when I run it directly on the geometries, and it takes forever if I try to compare `St_Union(A)` and `ST_Union(B)`, so not a solution either.

I am guessing I am not the first one to have such a need, and hoping there is an easy way to do that which I didn't found yet, do you know such a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have executed the `ST_DumpPoint` function, you can try the following query. For each vertex of your line a, the query finds out if a point on your line b is at a distance of 0. You will get the overlapping vertices as an output.

```
-- Change line_a with the name of the layer A
-- Change line_a with the name of the layer B
SELECT line_a.* 
FROM line_a, line_b
WHERE ST_DWithin(line_a.geom, line_b.geom, 0)
```

You have to execute the query with spatial indexes. It should run fast if you have 15000 points.

You can try an other function : `ST_OrderingEquals(line_a.geom, line_b.geom)`
which returns true if the 2 geometries are identical.

Comment: That's what I did, do you know how to implement spatial indexes in a CTE ? I did use a CTE.

Comment: For the indexes, the easiest way is to create tables, add the indexes, do your treatments and then delete your tables. You can also use temp tables. 
Using CTEs, your query should take a few minutes at most.

Comment: I edited my post with a new code.

Comment: Thank you, I went with that and it is satisfying (for making it more dynamic, I created a trigger updating those table when I udpate my geometries).

Comment: You're welcome ! good idea